# Как выполнить байт код внутри скрипта python?

Tags: python

Как сделать так чтоб скопировать содержимое .exe файла,переместить в переменное,а потом при помощи какого то метода выполнить содержимое переменной?попробовал и os.system() и subprocess.call(),ничего не работает!

```
import os
import time

a = b''
with open('file.exe', 'rb') as file_1:
       for i in file_1:
           a = a + i

file_1.close()
time.sleep(5)
os.system(a)
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что таких методов не существует. Хотя бы потому, что это должен быть тот еще трюк с обходом защиты современных процессоров и ОС. Для этого код надо сначала записать куда то как данные. Но современные процессоры не позволяют пользовательским программам писать в те же области, где лежит исполняемый код. Значит требуетсы поддержка этого со стороны ОС (переназначение сегментов данных и кода на одни и те же области). А они, опять же в целях безопасности, такой функционал предоставляют очень не охотно

Comment: Кроме того в exe файле помимо собственно выполнимого кода лежит масса исполнимой информации. И то что вы из него считали - это нельзя просто взять и выполнить на процессоре. Над этим еще должен поработать загрузчик ОС, который зная формат exe разделит его на данные и исполнимый код, после чего загрузит требуемые exe dll. После чего в поправит адреса в байткоде, для связи разных компонент. Подготовит сегменты. И после наконец передаст туда управление. Что собственно и делают методы вроде os.system, только они принимают именно имя файла, а не голые данные в памяти

Comment: ОС всегда выполняет программы из файлов (по крайней мере на уровне API пользователя.  То, что в данный момент копия такой программы уже загружена в память и может быть исполнена это механизмы внутренней оптимизации и вы на них не можете влиять). Поэтому вам надо записать свою переменную в  файл (с подходящими атрибутами доступа) и вызвать выполнение файла.

Comment: Есть corepy, который по идее позволяет запустить голый машинный код (не экзешник, а просто код без всяких заголовков) из python. Когда-то его пробовал, но не удалось "завести".

Answer (score 4):

Полностью согласен с [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933929/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-python#comment1549229_933929):

> Подозреваю, что таких методов не существует. Хотя бы потому, что это
> должен быть тот еще трюк с обходом защиты современных процессоров и
> ОС. Для этого код надо сначала записать куда то как данные. Но
> современные процессоры не позволяют пользовательским программам писать
> в те же области, где лежит исполняемый код. Значит требуетсы поддержка
> этого со стороны ОС (переназначение сегментов данных и кода на одни и
> те же области). А они, опять же в целях безопасности, такой функционал
> предоставляют очень не охотно