# Можно ли конвертировать файл exe в файлы bin?например при помощи python или специального софта?

Tags: python

При помощи python я превратил содержимое exe файла в шелл код,ну вы знаете типа 0x66/0x49/0x41/0x90 и так далее,но сомневаюсь что это именно чистый шелл код а не добавки Windows,а может я реально получил файл bin,не знаю,может есть софт который этим занимается?

Comment: чем "этим" софт должен заниматься? открывать любой файл как бинарный и читать байты?

Comment: Именно так и задумывалось!

Comment: что нужно сделать с фалом, поконкретнее задачу ставьте?

Comment: просто открыть для чтения `open('filename', 'rb')`

Comment: Я так и сделал,но вот другие сказали что это не правильно потому что байт код который содержит исполняемый файл и байт код который исполняет процессор при выполнении этого файла не идентичны,что вы по этому поводу думаете?

Comment: я нашел ответ,я этот вопрос задал для того,чтоб узнать как запустить исполняемый файл внутри скрипта python,думаю вам будет интересен ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933929/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-python/935792#935792